# HTTP web request exception - unable to connect to remote server

Tags: .net, iis, xmlhttprequest, windows-server-2012-r2

I wrote a small .NET application that connects to a remote host over http to retrieve data from it. It works fine on my local machine but when I published it to my production server the application doesn't seem to be able to make a successful connection with the remote host. I don't know what I'm missing here - any help will be appreciated.

This is a part of the .net trace log from the server:

```css
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [4972] Entering WebRequest::Create(https://tls1ca.imodulesapi.com/ws/21/GeneralQuery.asmx)
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [4972] Entering HttpWebRequest#39857290::HttpWebRequest(https://tls1ca.imodulesapi.com/ws/21/GeneralQuery.asmx#-1022471907)
System.Net Information: 0 : [4972] RAS supported: True
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [4972] Exiting HttpWebRequest#39857290::HttpWebRequest() 
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [4972] Exiting WebRequest::Create()  -> HttpWebRequest#39857290
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [4972] Entering HttpWebRequest#39857290::GetRequestStream()
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [4972] Entering ServicePoint#56908170::ServicePoint(tls1ca.imodulesapi.com:443)
System.Net Information: 0 : [4972] Associating HttpWebRequest#39857290 with ServicePoint#56908170
System.Net Information: 0 : [4972] Associating Connection#13418106 with HttpWebRequest#39857290
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [4856] Entering WebRequest::Create(https://tls1ca.imodulesapi.com/ws/21/GeneralQuery.asmx)
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [4856] Entering HttpWebRequest#60207123::HttpWebRequest(https://tls1ca.imodulesapi.com/ws/21/GeneralQuery.asmx#-1022471907)
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [4856] Exiting HttpWebRequest#60207123::HttpWebRequest() 
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [4856] Exiting WebRequest::Create()  -> HttpWebRequest#60207123
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [4856] Entering HttpWebRequest#60207123::GetRequestStream()
System.Net Information: 0 : [4856] Associating HttpWebRequest#60207123 with ServicePoint#56908170
System.Net Information: 0 : [4856] Associating Connection#56833753 with HttpWebRequest#60207123
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [4860] Entering WebRequest::Create(https://tls1ca.imodulesapi.com/ws/21/GeneralQuery.asmx)
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [4860] Entering HttpWebRequest#28387590::HttpWebRequest(https://tls1ca.imodulesapi.com/ws/21/GeneralQuery.asmx#-1022471907)
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [4860] Exiting HttpWebRequest#28387590::HttpWebRequest() 
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [4860] Exiting WebRequest::Create()  -> HttpWebRequest#28387590
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [4860] Entering HttpWebRequest#28387590::GetRequestStream()
System.Net Information: 0 : [4860] Associating HttpWebRequest#28387590 with ServicePoint#56908170
System.Net Information: 0 : [4860] Associating Connection#17693431 with HttpWebRequest#28387590
System.Net Error: 0 : [4972] Exception in HttpWebRequest#39857290:: - Unable to connect to the remote server.
```

Here is the exception from the browser:

```html
<!-- 
[SocketException]: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 104.18.230.150:443
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
[WebException]: Unable to connect to the remote server
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at IMWSInterface.Models.APIAccess.AddEnvelopToRequest(XmlDocument soapEnvelop, HttpWebRequest request)
   at IMWSInterface.Models.APIAccess.GetMemberId(String constitID)
   at IMWSInterface.Controllers.HomeController.Index()
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
-->
```

Comment: Is the target service under your control? It could be something to do with CORS, but it's hard to tell without seeing the exception. Could you run the app in a browser, bring up the debugging tools (usually F12) and capture the error?

Comment: thanks for your help Bill. I added the exception from the browser to the body

Comment: Sadly, this does not help much either! It says that the request timed out. Can you remote onto the machine which the web app is hosted and see if you can at least ping the service host?

Comment: strangely, I cant ping the remote host on the server... but I can access the API link on the browser (that's the link my app uses to make a connection with the remote host).. So I'm looking at the firewall settings to see if something is being blocked there.

Comment: Collect .NET network tracing on your local machine and compare the successful/failed cases. Then the cause should be clear.

Comment: it turned out to be a server configuration issue. It's resolved now! : )